# How can I prevent apps from going full screen and hiding the notification bar?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notification-bar

The notification bar takes only a few pixels yet contains so much useful information. Unfortunately, there are some apps (that I otherwise love) that insist on being in full screen, and therefore remove the notification bar from sight.

Is there any way I can force the notification bar to remain while running these apps?

I run rooted Marshmallow with Xposed Framework on a Samsung SM-G900F.

The apps can run on all types of display sizes and aspect ratios, so technically they should be able to do without those pixels on top.

Comment: Since you have xposed and rooted I have two options for you: 1. AppSettings (xposed) and Xhalo floating window (xposed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an app for your required feature [Status bar in full screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.jskt.togglestatusbar&hl=en)

You can use it with any launcher and it is compatible with Android 2.2+

In the app, you can toggle status bar on/off in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use [AppSettings xposed module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) which also has the feature to disable fulscreen mode:

[image]

Or [XHalo floating window](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.zst.xposed.halo.floatingwindow) which creates small floating windows when launching an application instead of full screen.

Comment: Tried it again. Still not working. This app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.binarytoys.speedometer